# Matching function of a regular expression in excel?

Tags: regex, excel, vba, excel-2010

I have several cells in my sheet which contain an [ISIN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Securities_Identification_Number).

Here is an example of an ISIN: `DE0006231004`

I have created a regular expression which matches the ISIN: 
`^[a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]{10}$`

I want to match this regex on my cell and give a 1 if it matches otherwise a 0.

Is this possible with a function?

Comment: I think this is suited for [Super User](http://superuser.com/about)

Comment: Not a question for superuser. OP is asking how to write a function. This is a programming question; it belongs here on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following function will do what you need. It will return either 0 (zero) if string doesn't match or 1 (one) if the string matches to pattern.

```
Function MatchISIN(ISIN As String)

    Dim regEx As Object
    Set regEx = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

    regEx.Pattern = "^[a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]{10}$"
    regEx.IgnoreCase = True
    regEx.Global = True

    Dim Matches As Object
    Set Matches = regEx.Execute(ISIN)

    MatchISIN = Matches.Count

End Function
```

Comment: You can also use `regEx.Test()` to return a boolean of whether or not it matches.  Technically Execute will continue searching long after it's found the first match to continue finding all matches.  Depending on the type of data, this could cause extra slowness, especially since we only need to test for a match in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the built-in `Like` method;

```
if "DE0006231009" like "[A-Za-z][A-Za-z]##########" then ...
```

Comment: THX for your answer! Does `like` match `DE0006231009` exactly, because I have several different `ISIN` numbers in my sheet?

Comment: It matches 2 letters of any case then exactly 10 numbers