# Excel NamedRange.Find Method with Regex pattern match in C#

Tags: c#, regex, excel, search

I need to search for the cell with the first occurrence of a string that matches a Regex pattern. MSDN documentation offers this:

```
// Find the first occurrence of "Seashell".
Excel.Range Range1 = namedRange1.Find("Seashell", missing, missing,
    Excel.XlLookAt.xlWhole, Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByColumns,
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlNext,
    false, false, missing);
```

Is there a a way to replace "Seashell" with the Regex pattern match code?

Thanks.

Comment: is this similar to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19784587/matching-function-of-a-regular-expression-in-excel
?

Comment: Looks like a good lead, thanks. I found a workaround, at least as far as the specific workbooks are concerned concerned, because I identified a column heading that never changes regardless of the template.

Answer (score 0):

You can use * for a wildcard, but I haven't been able to confirm any other regex works